how to set index by choosing in javascript
home pageIsecond page have a home page where I have 6 buttons displayed. Each button directs me to another page where I have some info and a "Discover" button. Normally each button should direct me to a specific link but I have a problem that my index is always set to 0 and it doesn't change.
I want the index to be depending on the solution the user chooses in the home page.


const solutions = [{}];

document.querySelectorAll('.discover-button').forEach(function(button, index) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var solutionIndex = index; console.log(solutionIndex);
    var videoIframe = document.getElementById('videoIframe');
    var videoUrl = solutions[solutionIndex].url;
    videoIframe.src = videoUrl;

    document.getElementById('iframeContainer').style.display = 'block';
  });
});

function closeIframe() {
  var videoIframe = document.getElementById('videoIframe');
  videoIframe.src = '';
  document.getElementById('iframeContainer').style.display = 'none';
}
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>

<div class="iframe-container" id="iframeContainer">
  <button class="close-iframe" onclick="closeIframe()">X</button>
  <iframe id="videoIframe" title="Video presentation"></iframe>
</div>




Please update the demo above so it shows your problem. Protip: Use let and const in 2024, instead of var.

When I run your snippet, clicking on a button logs the expected solutionIndex. Why do you think the index is wrong?

Which button is having the problem? There are 6 Discover buttons on the main page. You also mention a Discover button on the page that the button redirects to (in the iframe). If this is the button with the problem, you need to post that code.

You could add the button index as a parameter in the URL of the iframe src.

javascript and web development are not my field at all I am more AI and data science, but this is a web page that should display 6 use cases of AI, basically I have 6 use cases in my home page each one has its page with a discover button that displays a demo. My problem now that whatever the use case I click in is it always displays the same demo in the iframe I don't know why

I want the index to be set depending on the use case the user chooses

I added pictures for help

Your buttons are all identical, though; what are you expecting to be different? The second argument of forEach() will always be the index of the element in the array-like object you're iterating over.

In your example the index variable created in the forEach callback is available in the click event handler callback because of a thing in JS (and some other languages) called a "closure". So, the log is getting the correct index, as Barmar said. If you want to prevent the error it's throwing you have to define something for each index, like more anonymous empty objects ([{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]).

Just based on the code snippet you provided, line 5 correctly logs solutionIndex but line 7 is trying to access an element outside of the range of solutions.
As mykaf mentioned in the comments,

The second argument of forEach() will always be the index of the element in the array-like object you're iterating over.

Adding a url element to each object and at least six objects to the solutions array should work just fine:


const solutions = [
  {
    url: "https://loremflickr.com/680/800/atm,bank,money"
  },
  {
    url: "https://loremflickr.com/680/800/water,river,ocean,blue"
  },
  {
    url: "https://loremflickr.com/680/800/rodent,mouse,gerbil"
  },
  {
    url: "https://loremflickr.com/680/800/grafitti"
  },
  {
    url: "https://loremflickr.com/680/800/debian,nature"
  },
  {
    url: "https://loremflickr.com/680/800/sock,shoe"
  },
];

document.querySelectorAll('.discover-button').forEach(function(button, index) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var solutionIndex = index; console.log(solutionIndex);
    var videoIframe = document.getElementById('videoIframe');
    var videoUrl = solutions[solutionIndex].url;
    videoIframe.src = videoUrl;

    document.getElementById('iframeContainer').style.display = 'block';
  });
});

function closeIframe() {
  var videoIframe = document.getElementById('videoIframe');
  videoIframe.src = '';
  document.getElementById('iframeContainer').style.display = 'none';
}
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>
<button class="discover-button">Discover</button>

<div class="iframe-container" id="iframeContainer">
  <button class="close-iframe" onclick="closeIframe()">X</button>
  <iframe id="videoIframe" title="Video presentation"></iframe>
</div>



